# PyCharm Professional not recognizing .ipynb files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

PyCharm not recognizing .ipynb files:
[image: PyCharm not recognizing .ipynb files]

I installed 'jupyter notebook' using pip3 but whenever I create a jupyter notebook file on pycharm professional, it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check File Type settings for Jupyter notebooks - `ipynb` should be assigned to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked almost two years ago but for anyone with the same problem going forward, it appears as of Dec. 22, 2022, .ipynb files are only supported in PyCharm Professional:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html

From the link it says, "Available only in PyCharm Professional: download to try or compare editions."

The link suggests DataSpell as an alternative and the trial version is free. DataSpell also supports anaconda, R, and SQL.